# Buffered Image wouldn't load onto the JPanel object

Tags: java, swing

```
public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {
//Get top-left coordinate of drawPanel w.r.t screen
Point p = new Point(0, 0);
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, panel);

//Get the region with width and height of panel and 
// starting coordinates of p.x and p.y
Rectangle region = panel.getBounds();
region.x = p.x;
region.y = p.y;

//Get screen capture over the area of region
BufferedImage bi = null;
try {
    bi = new Robot().createScreenCapture( region );
} catch (AWTException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MyPaintBrush.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return bi; 
}
```

Now, I want to be able to load the image back onto the JPanel `drawPanel`. The following is my attempt but it wouldn't work:

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\Work Space\\Java\\Eclipse\\MyPaintBrush\\MyImage.png")); 
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    drawPanel.add(picLabel);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please show me how it's done.

Comment: The Class.getResource is not a general method for reading files;  it is for reading data embedded in an application's .jar file.  You probably want to pass a `File` to the ImageIO.read method instead of a URL.

Comment: Oh...I just picked it up from one of the questions here. Can you please show your version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the method of creating url object.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(saveImage);
```

The `getResource()` method was not designed for accessing files on disk, but in jar/war. I would skip this line and directly open a file, since it's on file system:

```
 BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/file/name.png"));
```

Remember to use proper path format for your file system.

Comment: I replaced the URL part with this: `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Work Space/Java/Eclipse/MyImage.png"));` and it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: doesn't file name should end with `.png` - Looks like you passed path to `MyPaintBrush` instead of  `MyPaintBrush.png`. Btw for me it looks like `MyPaintBrush` is a directory (your project name), not a file

Comment: My bad. I edited it right away and it still wouldn't work. Is the file path format that I typed correct?

Comment: No, for windows it should be D:\\folder\\  etc, change evey `/` to '\\'

Comment: Is image written on the disk to this path? Can you open it with default image viewer?

Comment: @Grendan "Doesn't work" is very vague and difficult to diagnose.  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, the exception is: `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!`

Comment: I tried `D:\Work Space\Java\Eclipse\MyImage.png` and `D:\\Work Space\\Java\\Eclipse\\MyImage.png`. The former doesn't even compile as it's in an invalid format.

Comment: @Kuba: Yes, I can open the file  just as any other image.

Comment: And you are 100% sure about the path? It is directly in "Eclipse" folder?

Comment: Yes, buddy, I just copy-pasted the address from the windows explorer. I'm 100% sure.

Comment: With this address: `"D:\\Work Space\\Java\\Eclipse\\MyPaintBrush\\MyImage.png"`, there is no exception thrown, but the JPanel still remains blank. It doesn't load the image.

Comment: After `drawPanel.add(...);` add this: `drawPanel.validate();` or `drawPanel.repaint();`

Comment: Forget the picture for the moment - just set text on this label and check if you can see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75730/discussion-between-kuba-and-grendan).

Comment: Code works. I just replaced the full path with the String that contained the file name.  You are THE man!!!! Thanks.

Comment: @Grendan, `I just replaced the full path with the String that contained the file name.` - wow, that is exactly what I suggested and showed you in the code I posted with my answer. I questioned why you were hard coding the directory path and stated you just need to use the file name. This answer suggested you needed to add the directory information. So I fail to see how it pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

> It took me an entire day to figure out (with much needed help here) how to save the bufferedimage of the JPanel onto my hard disk. I used the following code to do it:

I prefer to use the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class. It is packaged as a reusable class. Also the paint() method of JComponent() is faster than using a Robot.

> Now, I want to be able to load the image back onto the JPanel drawPanel.

When you created the file you didn't specify all the directory information, so why are you hardcoding the directory path when you attempt to read the file. Just use the same filename to read the field that you used to write the file.

Here is an example using the ScreenImage class that writes the image and immediately reads the image:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ImageReload extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel timeLabel;
    JLabel imageLabel;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("timeLabel.jpg");

    public ImageReload()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        imageLabel = new JLabel( timeLabel.getText() );

        add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    String imageName = "timeLabel.jpg";
                    BufferedImage image = ScreenImage.createImage(timeLabel);
                    ScreenImage.writeImage(image, imageName);

                    imageLabel.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imageName) ) ) );
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println( e );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ImageReload() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note this version just changes the Icon of the label. If you are creating a new JLabel on a visible GUI, then you would also need to invoke revalidate() on the panel so the label has the proper size to be painted.

Comment: How do I apply it to my version of the code posted above?

Comment: Please understand that all these things are totally new to me and I'm kinda freaking out inside. I spent a lot of time on my code. I just want to to show me how this approach can be applied to my code.

Comment: Your code is not complete. It is a few random line of code. I have no idea of the context of your your code is used. I gave you a complete code to download and execute. You need to spend a couple of minutes looking at the code and then implement the "concept" of the code into your program. Its 3 lines of code to create the image, and one line of code to read the image. Even if you don't use the ScreenImage class it is still only one line of code to read the image. All you need is to specify the filename correctly.

Comment: We are not here to write code for you, only point you in the right direction. It gets annoying when you delete postings (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751652/improving-a-paint-brush-app/29751799#29751799) because people don't write the code. Take the time to read these tutorials and then use the knowledge to modify your code. Nobody said programming is easy, but you don't learn if you don't try.

Comment: I deleted the question because I reluctantly posted my entire code hoping to get better help and I don't want it to be plagiarised.

Comment: That's my personal project and I don't want it to be on the internet.

Comment: So, why hasn't this answer been accepted yet? I proved that you can read in an image by just using its filename and setting the icon of a label. You don't need all the directory information. Learn from the simple example and use the knowledge in your program.

Comment: I would gladly accept it if it works. What are the import statements for ScreenImage? Eclipse doesn't recognize it.

Comment: So you didn't even take the time to download the ScreenImage class and test it?? It is not part of the JDK. You download the class and place it in a directory on your classpath the same way you would with any class that you create on your IDE.

Comment: Cimickr,I love you man. I really like you. I really appreciate your help. I know I've come across as a lazy dude but I respect your help. I'll definitely try out your suggestion.

Comment: You're a really nice guy. You help others find answers rather than just write code. I apologize about the deletions. I hope you see my perspective as well as I don't want my code to be up there.

Comment: `I don't want my code to be up there.` - We never want to see you entire project. We don't have time to read/understand the whole code. We want to see a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates the problem. The code I posted here is a SSCCE. It is minimal code that demonstrate a problem/solution.